# React Native, render function not rendering, although the trace indicates that passes through it

Tags: react-native, render, redux, navigator, react-redux

Solution added at the end of this question, inspired by https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6268 from @grabbou

The curtain rises and the first scene 'Scene1' appears. Scene1 is a presentational component wrapped with '`connect`' from `react-redux` framework to bind the status and actions to their props.
Actions work perfectly well and renders the state, the counter, on the screen.

Cliking forward to the second scene 'Scene2', exactly the same as the first component, but the props (the same as Scene1) are passed through `passProps` in `renderScene`  within the `Naviagator`.

Every thing is OK, the actions are dispatched correctly, you can see on the trace, `render` function is invoked for painting the counter, again you can see in the trace, but DOES NOT WORK!. The inner component logs that is in the Scene1! What's wrong?

This is the trace, after going directly to Scene2 and click twice on <+> to increment the state.

[image: The trace]

It's a bug-Native React?

I am using

- "react-native": "0.19.0",
- "react-redux": "4.1.2",
- "redux": "3.1.7",

This is all the code, if you can help me.
There are no concession to stylize the presentation, so the result on the screen is very simple.

**1.** The simple code of **index.ios.js**

```jsx
    'use strict';
    import React, {
      AppRegistry,
    } from 'react-native';

    import App from './src/App'

    AppRegistry.registerComponent('App', () => App);
```

And **2.** this is the code of the **App.js**:

```jsx
'use strict';
import React, {
  Navigator,
  Component,
  View, ListView, ScrollView,
  Text, TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';

import { Provider, connect } from "react-redux";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers, bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import thunkMiddleware from "redux-thunk";
import createLogger from "redux-logger";
```

**2.1** The **redux** part

```jsx
// REDUX BEGIN
//Actions
const INCREMENT = 'INCREMENT'
const DECREMENT = 'DECREMENT'
//Actions creators
const increment = () => ({ type: INCREMENT })
const decrement = () => ({ type: DECREMENT })
//Redux Initial State
const initialState = {
  counter: 0
}
//Reducer
const reducer = (state = initialState, action = {}) => {
  let delta = 1
  switch (action.type) {
  case DECREMENT: delta = -1;
  case INCREMENT:
    return Object.assign({}, state, { counter: state.counter+delta })
  default:
    return state
  }
}
//Redux Middelware
const loggerMiddleware = createLogger();
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(
  thunkMiddleware,
  loggerMiddleware
)(createStore);
//Wrapper to bind state and actions to props on Presentational Component
const connectComponent = (component) => connect(
    (state) => ({
      counter: state.counter
    }),
    (dispatch) => ({
      increment: () => dispatch(increment()),
      decrement: () => dispatch(decrement())
    })
  )(component)
// REDUX END
```

**2.2** The **App root**, with the **Provider** and the **Navigator**

```jsx
// APP
export default class App extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducer, initialState)}>
        <Navigator style={{flex: 1}}

          initialRoute={{
            name: 'Scene1',
            component: connectComponent(Scene1),
          }}

          renderScene={ (route, navigator) => {
            const Component = route.component;
            return (
              <View style={{flex: 1, marginTop:40}}>
                <Component navigator={navigator} route={route} {...route.passProps} />
              </View>
            );
          }}
        />
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

**2.3.**
The inner Component in both scenes to render the counter.
Has some traces, to show that the `shouldComponentUpdate` is triggered and return True (you has to Update!) with the time traced to show that is invoqued just some milliseconds after an action is dispatched.
And other to show that the `render` function is reached, **but doesn't not render** with in the Scene2. 
The trace show that this component always he thought that was the Scene1!!

```jsx
class Counter extends Component{
  constructor (props, context){
    super(props, context);
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){

    //Begin log
    const repeat = (str, times) => (new Array(times + 1)).join(str);
    const pad = (num, maxLength) => repeat(`0`, maxLength - num.toString().length) + num;
    const formatTime = (time) => `@ ${pad(time.getHours(), 2)}:${pad(time.getMinutes(), 2)}:${pad(time.getSeconds(), 2)}.${pad(time.getMilliseconds(), 3)}`;
    console.log('shouldComponentUpdate '+this.props.route.name+ ': '+ (nextProps.counter !== this.props.counter) +' '+formatTime(new Date()));
    //End log

    return nextProps.counter !== this.props.counter;
  }


  render() {
    console.log('onRender: '+this.props.counter);
    return (
      <View>
        <Text style={{fontSize: 100}}>{this.props.counter}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{this.props.increment()}} ><Text style={{fontSize: 40}}>{'<'}+{'>'}</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{this.props.decrement()}} ><Text style={{fontSize: 40}}>{'<'}-{'>'}</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <Text>----</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

**2.4.**
The two scenes, are equals, just the button to forward or backward

```jsx
class Scene1 extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text style={{fontSize: 40}}>Scene1</Text>
        <Counter {...this.props}/>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{
          this.props.navigator.push({
            name: 'Scene2',
            component: Scene2,
            passProps: {...this.props}
           })
        }}>
          <Text style={{fontSize: 20}}>{'<'}Forward{'>'} to Scene2</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  }
}


class Scene2 extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text style={{fontSize: 40}}>Scene2</Text>
        <Counter {...this.props}/>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{
          this.props.navigator.pop()
        }} >
            <Text style={{fontSize: 20}}>{'<'}Back{'>'} to Scene1</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

At the end some 'hard copy' to show the 'show'

The Scene2 showing the counter, and the two buttons to dispatch actions.
Clicking theses actions doesn't render the counter, but the actions are dispatched correctly.
[image: The Scene2 showing the counter]

After just going to Scene2 and two clicks on <+> to increment the counter.

The `Counter` component is his trace show the `route.name`, but it it show is on Scene1! What is wrong here?

[image: The trace]

Well, the play is over, the curtain has fallen.

It is a very dramatic scene. (Just the Scene2)

I wonder why it does not work.

Native React issue?

Thanks to all

### **The Solution**

from https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6268

@grabbou inspired the changes, he proposes wrap the all App as a Container and then pass Store and Actions as simple props to all Scenes.

To make these changes create a new component the RootComponent and render the App connected to the Redux Store and Actions like this.

```jsx
export default class RootComponent extends Component {
  render () {
    const AppContainer = connectComponent(App); //<< App has to be container
    return (
      <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducer, initialState)}>
        <AppContainer/>
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

Then App change removing the Provider and just passing the Scene1 as dumb component, and renderScene pass {...this.props} insted of {...route.passProps}

```jsx
class App extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
        <Navigator style={{flex: 1}}

          initialRoute={{
            name: 'Scene1',
            component: Scene1,
          }}

          renderScene={ (route, navigator) => {
            const Component = route.component;
            return (
              <View style={{flex: 1, marginTop:40}}>
                <Component navigator={navigator} route={route} {...this.props} />
              </View>
            );
          }}
        />
    )
  }
}
```

The remove passProps from navigator.push in Scene1, because already are passed as default in renderScene

```jsx
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{
          this.props.navigator.push({
            name: 'Scene2',
            component: Scene2,
            //passProps: {...this.props}
           })
        }}>
```

And this is all folks!

Thanks

Comment: Awesome that you answered your own question and provided a solution. Might I suggest however that rather than tacking it on to the end of your question, you instead add it as an actual answer? This way, it will show up as answered in searches.

Comment: Thanks @Chris Geirman,

In an other questions that i added new stuff as response, some one of the reviers tell me that i can not add response to my question, so I added the solution editing the question

Comment: Ok, I copy/pasted your solution as the solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

> NOTE: This is merely a copy/paste of the author provided solution above.

from https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6268

@grabbou inspired the changes, he proposes wrap the all App as a Container and then pass Store and Actions as simple props to all Scenes.

To make these changes create a new component the RootComponent and render the App connected to the Redux Store and Actions like this.

```js
export default class RootComponent extends Component {
  render () {
    const AppContainer = connectComponent(App); //<< App has to be container
    return (
      <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducer, initialState)}>
        <AppContainer/>
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

Then App change removing the Provider and just passing the Scene1 as dumb component, and renderScene pass {...this.props} insted of {...route.passProps}

```
class App extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
        <Navigator style={{flex: 1}}

          initialRoute={{
            name: 'Scene1',
            component: Scene1,
          }}

          renderScene={ (route, navigator) => {
            const Component = route.component;
            return (
              <View style={{flex: 1, marginTop:40}}>
                <Component navigator={navigator} route={route} {...this.props} />
              </View>
            );
          }}
        />
    )
  }
}
```

The remove passProps from navigator.push in Scene1, because already are passed as default in renderScene

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{
      this.props.navigator.push({
        name: 'Scene2',
        component: Scene2,
        //passProps: {...this.props}
       })
    }}>
```

And this is all folks!

Thanks